# Is there a more efficient way of selecting data from a dynamic table than using a temp table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, temp-tables

I've got a table that can contain a variety of different types and fields, and I've got a table definitions table that tells me which field contains which data. I need to select things from that table, so currently I build up a dynamic select statement based on what's in that table definitions table and select it all into a temp table, then work from that.

The actual amount of data I'm selecting is quite big, over 5 million records. I'm wondering if a temp table is really the best way to go around doing this.

Are there other more efficient options of doing what I need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data is static, reports like - cache most popular queries results, preferably on Application Server. Or do multidimensional modeling (cubes).  That is the really "more efficient option to do that".

Temp tables, table variables, table data types... In any case you will use your tempdb, and if you want to optimize your queries, try to optimize tempdb storage (after checking [IO statistics](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184361.aspx) ). You can aslo create indexes for your temp tables.

Comment: Didn't know you can index temp tables, I'll look into that. Thanks :)

Comment: Yes you can! And more, you can create indexes AFTER the table is populated. I found that, in general, works better that way.

Comment: Btw, if you are getting trouble chewing 5M rows at once you can do it inside a loop to process a 10 thousand each time. If did right way that ill consume a lot less memory. <pseudo code>While select top 10k from mytable not in (select from processed) process it!</pseudo code>

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Table Variables` to achieve the functionality.
If you are using the same structure in multiple queries, you can go for custom defined `Table data types` as well.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188927.aspx

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522526(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: frankly,show small data with with both table structure

Comment: As a rule of thumb temp tables performs slight better with large data. For that 5M rows I can avoid using table variables.